# Creating/registering a user (of a custom profile type) when a certain webform is submitted?

Tags: 7, entities, users, webforms

Before all else - Here's my current code.

```
function hook_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {

  $password = user_password(8);

  //set up the user fields
  $new_user = array(
    'name' => $form_state['values']['e_mail'],
    'mail' => $form_state['values']['e_mail'],
    'pass' => $password,
    'status' => 0,
    'init' => $email,
    'roles' => array(
      DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user', 
      6 => 'custom role',
    ),
    'field_dealer_fname'=> $form_state['values']['first_name'];
    'field_dealer_lname' => $form_state['values']['last_name'];
    'field_dealer_company' => $form_state['values']['company_name'];
    'field_dealer_phone' => $form_state['values']['phone'];
  );
 $account = user_save(null, $new_user)

    ->execute();
}
```

I'm very new to Drupal, but intermediate experienced in Web dev in general. I just recently inherited a client from a previous employee before I joined, and he exclusively used Drupal (7, at that.)

Anyways, he previously had a system to set up a new user through this user-submitted webform, but that functionality apparently died 2 months ago in some sort of host migration. Now, I'm trying to figure out a way to accomplish this task with the already existing webform (v 3.27) and database.

That being said, from what I've found, I'm trying to use a webform Submission Hook to call the (Webform) values

```
first_name,
last_name,
company_name,
phone,
e_mail
```

to fill the adjacent (Custom) user profile fields of "Dealer_profile" (along with the default ones)

```
field_dealer_fname
field_dealer_lname
field_dealer_company
field_dealer_phone
```

So, referring back to my code, my thought process is:

```
//create a random 8 char password
  $password = user_password(8);
```

I was thinking this would be the equivalent of saying "these profile values = this user submitted value"

```
//set up the user fields
  $new_user = array(
    'name' => $form_state['values']['e_mail'],
    'mail' => $form_state['values']['e_mail'],
    'pass' => $password,
    'status' => 0,
    'init' => $email,
    'roles' => array(
      DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user', 
      6 => 'custom role',
    ),
    'field_dealer_fname'=> $form_state['values']['first_name'];
    'field_dealer_lname' => $form_state['values']['last_name'];
    'field_dealer_company' => $form_state['values']['company_name'];
    'field_dealer_phone' => $form_state['values']['phone'];
  );
```

and ultimately, save this information and execute the hook?

```
 $account =    user_save(null, $new_user)

    ->execute();
```

However, I feel like the hook itself is also wrong. This whole hooking thing in Drupal is a little odd to me, coming from mostly Wordpress use. Unfortunately the documentation is a little barebones, or in some way difficult for me to figure out how these things actually work. I was also just kind of thrown into this, and just have to figure everything out! Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can add your code and add inside sites\all\modules\webform\includes\webform.submissions.inc in functions named "webform_submission_insert" , and check if it works or not , also as per below image in $submission variable you will get all webform submitted values .

[image]

Also , if you want to Get Webfrom submitted data by userid wise use below code anywhere.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
$values = webform_get_submissions($nid, null, $user->uid, 1);
```

if you want to Get Webfrom submitted data by node id , as below code 105 is node id.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');  
$submissions = webform_get_submissions(105);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing how this should look - i've added the last bit of node-specific code to the top, inserted my code haphazardly into the beginning of `webform_submission_insert`, and changed `$form_state` to `$submission`, just because that made sense at the time. Of course, still no new user being created. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, You are trying to save your webform submission data and using that field generate new user . right ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct. I haven't been able to find anything that works for me yet.

Comment: Hey, i have checked below code in my project , which will generate new user when you will submit webform . check this img : http://prntscr.com/flfgck

Comment: as you mention in above question there need modification of user save code as per my screenshot http://prntscr.com/flfgck , please try this one it will surely work for you.